# SQL Server: can a stored proc that updates tables be called from within a CLR UDF

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I don't know why, but CLR User Defined Functions are not allowed to update tables.

Is it possible to work around this restriction by calling a stored procedure from the CLR UDF that updates tables for it ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't create a CLR stored procedure instead of a function?

Comment: I could rewrite it as a stored procedure, but that would require a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not CLR UDF, it is any  <strike>RDBMS</strike>   UDF function, by definition, cannot change the state of a database, i.e. engage:

- DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE (i.e. DML) statements,
- calls to stored procedure,
- permanently change the value of server environment variable,
- etc.
  as well as use calls to nondeterministic (with the same input returning different results) functions (like GETDATE(), NEWID(), etc.)

Update:
Oops, SQL Server 2008 relaxed the restrictions on use of non-deterministic functions. 
If UDF uses non-deterministic, then it is treated as non-deterministic.

One can check it by:

```
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.FunctionName'),'IsDeterministic')
```

Comment: You are correct:  if I attempt to call a stored procedure from a UDF, I get an error message that states that only functions and "...some extended stored procedures..." can be called from within a UDF.  Ugh - back to the drawing board.